# Where to start learning to become a successful Oracle DBA

Tags: oracle

I am IT Graduate with good knowledge on SQL and C. I have done most of the SQL programming on Microsoft SQL Server in my academics. But i want to become Oracle DBA. Could you please suggest me a structural way to to start learning.  And also please suggest me what background work is needed before digging into it.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the [Oracle Concepts Guide (pdf)](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_pdf?pathname=server.112/e25789.pdf). It will give you a good overview of everything related to Oracle databases and will give you a framework in which to place everything else you learn about Oracle.  While you will by no means be a DBA after reading the guide, this is where you should start.

Answer (score 4):

As a focus on more "soft skills" and career planning, I highly suggest "How to Become an Exceptional DBA" by Brad McGehee.  It's a free e-book found [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/how-to-become-an-exceptional-dba,-2nd-edition/). It is a little geared towards a SQL Server career, but the tenet apply to all DBA careers.